# computing an intergral with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, integration

Hi I have a equation like the following that I want to calculate.

The equation is given by :

[image]

In this equation x is an arrary from 0 to 500. 
The value of t = 500 i.e upper limit of the integration.

Now I want to compute c as c(500,x).

The code that I have written so far is as follows:

```
x <- seq(from=0,by=0.5,length=1000)
t=500

integrand <- function(t)t^(-0.5)*exp((-x^2/t)-t)
integrated <- integrate(integrand, lower=0, upper=t)
final <-  pi^(-0.5)*exp(2*x)*integrated
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in integrate(integrand, lower = 0, upper = t) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In -x^2/t :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In -x^2/t - t :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In t^(-0.5) * exp(-x^2/t - t) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

But it doesn't work because there is a variable x inside the integrand which is an arrary. Can anyone suggest how can I compute the integration first and then calculate the total expression for each value of x ? If I change the value of x in the integrand to constant I can compute integration but I want to compute for all the values of x from 0 to 500.

Thank you so much.

Comment: When using `integrate` the function needs to vary with the name of the variable that is being integrated, which in your case is \theta rather than "x".

Comment: I understand that. How can I change the expression with x outside of the integrand. It seems the exponential function is connected with both x and thita. How can I separate those variables ?

Comment: generally one would use `sapply( vector, FUN=...)` and write up you FUN to take a single X variable. But do not call it "x" because you need that to be the variable that gets passed to `integrate`. What's the background of this problem?

Comment: This is a solution of the continuous release of a dye in a 1 D channel.

Comment: The reason I ask is that my R solution breaks down for some values of X and that may depend on how you are presenting the problem. At one point you said x was an array of 500 and another point you said the limits of integration were to 500. It seemed as though you were conflating their roles.

Comment: @DWin I was trying to look upto 500 metres only thats why I said that x is an array of 500. Actually, the limit of x is from -infinity to infinity.

Comment: @Dwin So, I can't solve this problem simply using the functions mentioned above. Is that true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is some code, but it blows up after t=353:

```
Cfun <- function(XX, upper){
      integrand <- function(x)x^(-0.5)*exp((-XX^2/x)-x)
      integrated <- integrate(integrand, lower=0, upper=upper)$value
      (final <-  pi^(-0.5)*exp(2*XX)*integrated) }
sapply(1:400, Cfun, upper=500)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this code. I don't know why the equation behaved weird after t=353. But at least I can look the profile before t=353. Thanks.

Comment: Be sure use a graphical view: `plot( sapply(1:300, Cfun, upper=500) );  lines(sapply(1:300, Cfun, upper=500) )`

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the loop over values for x outside the integration.  Iterate over the x-values and perform the integration for each one inside.  Then you'll have `C(x)` as a function of x suitable for plotting.

You realize, of course, that the indefinite integral can be evaluated:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+exp%28-%28c%2Bt%5E2%29%2Ft%29%2Fsqrt%28t%29

Maybe that will help you see what the answer looks like before you get started.

Comment: In that integral expression `x` is a constant.

Comment: Yes, I know.  You'll substitute a value for x and get the value of the integral.  Keep arrays of x and c and you'll have a plot of c versus x.

Comment: @duffmyo : Thank you so much for your solution. Can you suggest what should the syntax should be ? The link to the wolframalpha was very useful. I am new to R so I am having problem with syntax.

Comment: Sorry, not enough of an expert in R to dash it off.  I will think about it and try and post whatever might be helpful.  I'm trying to learn R, too.

Comment: I do not think the Wolfram expression was constructed properly. The variable of integration is not squared in the numerator of the exp argument.

Comment: I think it's just algebra.  I interpreted the integrand to be exp(-theta-x^2/theta)/sqrt(theta).  If you move the division by theta outside it comes out right.  Check me and see.